# how do i get a url parameter link /#parameter

Tags: html, node.js, http, express

I have seen websites that have url parameters in the form of `example.org/#Parameter`, instead of `example.org/?parameter=123`. I am not talking about a url that scrolls the page to the id of an element, but rather in express.js, extract the value that comes after the `#` in the url. how can I do this?

Comment: The hash part of the URL is not sent to the server by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the global variable `window.location.hash` for get the value of hash variable of some URL.

Additionally you can catch hash value changes using the bellow jquery function:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() { 
    //some code
});
```

EDIT:
As far as a know, the `window.location.hash` **is never sent to server/middleware**, so it's not possible to obtain this parameters on express.
You should use the query strings parameter (`example.org?parameter=123`) instead.

Comment: This question is asking about how to do it in Express, not the client's browser.